# Can't import some libraries in android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley, implementation, android-workmanager

I implemented volley library (implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1') but when I try to write StringRequest in MainActivity it doesn't import.

I had the same problem with Manager implementeation.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.